# Scrolltop global variable not updating on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, global-variables, scrolltop

Been messing with this for some time now, but I can't seem to be able to acces my `scrollTop` variable outside the `window.scroll` function.

I could obviously put my code in the `scroll` function. However, my code will be read every time I scroll, which I do not want. I want to check if `scrollTop` is greater than 50 (for example) then run a couple of lines of code once and move on.

I want to know how much the user has scrolled on my page. That's what does scrollTop function does. However I want to be able to check the scrollTop variable outside the scroll function. Though, for some reason it doesn't work. Neither with or without document.ready.

Here's my code so far:

```js
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    });
    
    $('.label').html(scrollTop + 'px');
```

Comment: what is flight_plane_pos...& where is it coming from ?

Comment: That's one of the variables I have. I shortened up my code a bit to make it more clear what I am trying to achieve. I've edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, you want to perform some action once each time the window scrolls past 50px.

Instead of keeping track of your **scrollTop** at the "global" (in the case above docReady) level, you should keep track of a **scrolledPast** variable that tracks the state of your scrolling and is updated in the **scroll** callback.  If the **scrolledPast** variable is false, but your **scrollTop** is > 50, set the variable & run your code.  The next time the **scroll** callback is run (probably very quickly thereafter), the **scrolledPast** variable will be set to true, so don't run the code.  Reset the **scrolledPast** variable when you scroll back up under 50.

Code time:

```js
var scrolledPast = false; //global flag
$(function() { //doc ready
    $(window).on('scroll', function() { //let's handle this, eh?
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > 50 && !scrolledPast) { //just scrolling past 50
          scrolledPast = true;
          myCode();
        }
        else if (scrollTop <= 50) { //reset our flag
          scrolledPast = false;
        }
    });
 });
 
 function myCode() {
    //scrolled past 50, do stuff!
    console.log('You did it!');
 }
```

```css
div {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  This is gonna be yuuuuuggggeeee!
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks! That's pretty much what I wanted. This'll allow me to continue work for now.

However, I want to perform way more actions past different heights throughout my website. It could work, but I feel like it'd become a mess quickly.

Is it possible to make it work the way I made the script in my original post?
I need to know what the scrollTop is outside the scroll function.

So.. ScrollTop updates at every scroll, doesn't it? Each time scrollTop gets updates, it should be updated in the scrollTop variable, but it doesn't work for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: You might want to add some more code then to make it clear what you're trying to do.  From the example you gave above you aren't using the scrollTop variable after it has been set in the scroll handler.  The one place it is used, **$('.label').html(scrollTop + 'px');**, only runs once on document ready.  If that is thing thing you're trying to update as the page scrolls, I'd look into [CSS position: fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately position fixed is something completely different from what I want.

I want to know how much the user has scrolled on my page. That's what does scrollTop function does. However I want to be able to check the scrollTop variable outside the scroll function. Though, for some reason it doesn't work. Neither with or without document.ready.

I hope it's more clear this time.